# Upload packages to respositories

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!
Im working on a Pharo library for writing ROS nodes, also in some tools based on this technology and some commands for infraestructure.

I am wanting to start to use apt-get for installation because of facility. I was thinking in upload in ubuntu developer, but then im quite sure it will be better to have it here.

How do i get a space for uploading my work? I searched through site and google without cool results, there is any tutorial? there is any standar process?

Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119376/upload-packages-to-respositories/) by [sbragagnolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3205/sbragagnolo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 203 on 2014-01-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS has nice and powerful releasing envionment.

"Releasing" your package allows you to install your package via debian binary (ie. via `apt-get` on Ubuntu). You can start from looking at "Get Involved" wiki page and specifically at [Release Binary Packages](http://wiki.ros.org/Get%20Involved#Release_Binary_Packages) section, where its [tutorial using bloom](http://www.ros.org/wiki/bloom/Tutorials/) is linked from.

Before starting that tutorial, you have to have at least your package publicly accessible on a distributed revision control system such as github, code.google.com, bitbucket etc. Being comfortable with [SCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_management) tools (eg. git, svn, hg) would be very helpful (or almost required) if you're not yet.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sbragagnolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3205/sbragagnolo/) on 2014-01-20**:
Thank you very much! It's very usefull information!